# Are typescript configuration options case-sensitive?

Tags: typescript

In `tsconfig.json` files I've seen variations of the `compilerOptions.libs` values with TypeScript v5. In some places it is uppercase:

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2022", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
  }
```

while elsewhere it is lowercase:

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2022", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
  }
```

Is there any difference in how these values will be interpreted?

Comment: The casing is irrelevant, it all has to get lowercased to look up the declaration files anyway. Even the JSON schema would allow `"DoM.ItErAbLe"` (but, you know, don't).

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428057/asking-question-getting-difficult-day-by-day).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TL;DR* no, there is no difference.

---

The list of libs can be found in the Typescript source code in [src/lib/libs.json](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v5.3.3/src/lib/libs.json).

Excerpt...

> ```json
> {
>    "libs": [
>        // JavaScript only
>         "es5",
>         "es2015",
>         "es2016",
>         "es2017",
>         "es2018",
>         "es2019",
>         "es2020",
>         "es2021",
>         "es2022",
>         "es2023",
>         "esnext",
> ```

You can see that all of the names are lowercase, as are the accompanying `.d.ts` filenames.

When comparing the values in your `tsconfig.json`, Typescript normalises the values provided by lowercasing them.